# How to add a static item on a GridView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate, microsoft-metro

As you can see the images above, the GridView has already the feeds or items, but these ones contains static items.

[image]

In this image, the item which I'm interest is 'See More'. I want to implement something like that in my application.

[image]

In this another app, contains two static items:

- All starts
- Top free.

Not, the question is, how can I add this item in the GridView? and when pressed.. execute something (like a button or command).

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** A partner told me "You can edit template of the gridview and add your controls next to the itemspresenter"

I don't have so much experience customizing control's templates. Could you show me an example doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an item to your DataSource.

**For example**
If your data source is an List of Product items and you take them from the file.
First pick items from file and populate your list. Than create an object with specific data (your static data) add add it the list. That way you'll be able to manage this item and it always be in good place

Comment: What if you want that item to look totally different than the others defined by the item template?

Comment: @SamiRajala first of all this is question for another topic. But take a look at that: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/966aa897-1413-46f0-bef7-663de36f9423 You need to get to know with Variable Sized Grid View